# Rails performance Test

Tags: performance, ruby-on-rails-3, testing

In a part of a controller, I query in an heavy manner my db.
 I'm wondering if to use the ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(complex query), or if to use a combination of finder. In order to find out the better way, I would like to submit some performance test on the application.
 I find an easy way to make such tests, the problem is that the instruction on this link: "*http://guides.rubyonrails.org/performance_testing.html*"; **doesn't work on Rails 3**, it reports me this error: `... 'run': uninitialized constant BrowsingTest:STARTED  (NameError).` 
Can someone give me some tips ?
tnx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please note down steps you took to arrive at the error.  It would help.  Here's a general answer:

Initially, make sure that performance is your actual problem.  If it actually is...

[Here's](http://www.slideshare.net/Blaine/scaling-twitter) an interesting starting point.  I like the bit on using message-passing for synchronization, Erlang.  Indexes can be handy too.